# pandas extract() returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

Could you please give me a hand here?

I have the result of a dataframe split() [which I believe is a dataframe where each row is a list?] like this:

```
0 [001, 2491010000, Blah, 99, Blah, Blah, 2,57]
1 [01.01.20, 0048000002, 21.02.20, #176627, #176627, 001, 2491010000, Blah, 89, Blah, 70.418,60]
2 [01.01.20, Blah, 21.02.20, #176627, 001, 2491010000, Blah, 89, Blah, 3.258,67]
```

I would like to iterate the above and create a new dataframe like this:

```
Code         Code1     Price
2491010000   99        2,57
2491010000   89        70.418,60
2491010000   89        3.258,67
```

I used the snippet:

```
t = journal.str.extract(r'00\d\D{2}(\d{10})\D+(\d{2})\D+(\d+[,.]\d+[,.]\d+)',)
t
```

but t returns as empty. I tested the regex in [the regex simulator](https://www.regex101.com) and seems to work fine so I suspect the problem lies with the input 'journal'.

Could you show me the right way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Try `df[['Code', 'Code1', 'Price']] = df['journal'].str.extract(r'00\d\D*(\d{10})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)+)', expand=True)`

Comment: I think the problem persists because journal is a dtype('O') that was created after concatenating two splits. I 'll keep the more sophisticated regex though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn’t match the data. I’ve found 2 issues:

- `\d+[,.]\d+[,.]\d+` always wants 2 commas or dots, but your first line only has 1 comma and 0 dots
- `00\d\D{2}(\d{10})` expects 2 non-number separators between the 3-digit number and the 10-digit number, but there likely is either just one or more than 2 (I can’t tell because i only have the split data in your question, not the original data).

I changed the Price matching regex to `(\d{,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d+)`, if you don’t always expect to have numbers after the decimal separator you could also use `(\d{,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)`

- `?:` mark non-capturing groups, so they won’t be returned by extract
- putting the thousands separator in with the next digits allows to know there’s always 3 of them, and this 4-character block can be repeated as many times as necessary.

I also changed the `00\d` to `\d{10}` separator to `\s+` which means *any number of whitespace characters*.  Starting the regex with a word-break marker `\b` also allows to make sure `00\d` is a word on its own and not the end of another number.

```
>>> journal.str.extract(r'\b00\d\s+(\d{10})\D+(\d{2})\D+(\d{,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d+)')
            0   1          2
0  2491010000  99       2,57
1  2491010000  89  70.418,60
2  2491010000  89   3.258,67
```

You could name your capture groups directly in the regex:

```
>>> journal.str.extract(r'\b00\d\s+(?P<Code>\d{10})\D+(?P<Code1>\d{2})\D+(?P<Price>\d{,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d+)')
         Code Code1      Price
0  2491010000    99       2,57
1  2491010000    89  70.418,60
2  2491010000    89   3.258,67
```

That can help readers figure out what each capturing block does, but it also adds clutter. Up to personal preference.

Comment: Please do not omit the `0` min limiting quantifier value, the regex best practice is to always use it.

Comment: It does not work (sometimes, it makes the regex invalid, sometimes, returns unexpected matches as it is parsed incorrectly by the regex library) in some regex flavors if you omit the 0. It is safer to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

If the frame isn't too big and to keep the regex smaller you could try:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

'''
"[001, 2491010000, Blah, 99, Blah, Blah, 2,57]"
"[01.01.20, 0048000002, 21.02.20, #176627, #176627, 001, 2491010000, Blah, 89, Blah, 70.418,60]"
"[01.01.20, Blah, 21.02.20, #176627, 001, 2491010000, Blah, 89, Blah, 3.258,67]"
'''

df = pd.read_csv('df_strings.csv', header=None)

print(df, '\n')

                                                   0
0      [001, 2491010000, Blah, 99, Blah, Blah, 2,57]
1  [01.01.20, 0048000002, 21.02.20, #176627, #176...
2  [01.01.20, Blah, 21.02.20, #176627, 001, 24910... 


def getValues(x):
    code = re.search(r'(\d{10})', x).group(1)
    code1 = re.search(r'\s(\d{2}),', x).group(1)
    price = re.search(r'(\d+,\d+)', x).group(1)
    price = price.replace(',', '.')
    return pd.Series([code, code1, price])

df[['code', 'code1', 'price']] = df.apply(lambda x: getValues(x[0]), axis=1)

print(df[['code', 'code1', 'price']])

         code code1   price
0  2491010000    99    2.57
1  0048000002    89  418.60
2  2491010000    89  258.67
```